# function with input parameters that will convert them into a list inside its body

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, parameters

Is there a way to create a function like the one below and then to have those parameters being added to a list inside the function's body?

```py
def create_list(x, y, z, w, t):
```

Comment: *then to have those parameters being added to a list inside the function's body* - how do you mean? You can just do `my_list = [x, y, z, w, t]`...?

Comment: yes, I mean to generate some code that will basically pass all my parameters into a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you must make use of `*args` in your function that would be defined something like this

```py
def make_list(*args):
    return list(args)

print(make_list(1,2,3, "Spiderman", ("Gilfoyle", "Dinesh", "Richard"), {"wizardName": "Harry Potter", "age": 21}))
```

### Output for the above code

```sh
[1, 2, 3, 'Spiderman', ('Gilfoyle', 'Dinesh', 'Richard'), {'wizardName': 'Harry Potter', 'age': 21}]
```

Here you can pass any number of arguments of any type and they will be converted into a list and returned back to you. We need to write `return list(args)` because it returns a tuple by default. Since you require a list, we need the `list()` function to be called.

### Reference

1. [*args and **kwargs in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/)